# How to quickly check which files in a folder need updating and which don't using Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We use [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) for our code repository. Is it possible to check all files in a folder to see which files are in need of updating against those that don't need to be?

We often need to do this in order to work out whether it is safe just to perform an update on a folder and its contents below.

Comment: Tortoise SVN is a subversion client that is integrated with Windows Explorer. If you want to see what files in a directory need to be changed, the icon decorations for each file will show you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `Check for Modifications...` dialog, you can click the `Check Repository` button to see which files have been modified by other users since your last update.  From the [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html):

> It's often very useful to know which files you have changed and also
>   which files got changed and committed by others. That's where the
>   command **TortoiseSVN** → **Check For Modifications...** comes in handy. This
>   dialog will show you every file that has changed in any way in your
>   working copy, as well as any unversioned files you may have.
>
> If you click on the **Check Repository** then you can also look for
>   changes in the repository. That way you can check before an update if
>   there's a possible conflict. You can also update selected files from
>   the repository without updating the whole folder. By default, the
>   **Check Repository** button only fetches the remote status with the
>   checkout depth of the working copy. If you want to see all files and
>   folders in the repository, even those you have not checked out, then
>   you have to hold down the **Shift** key when you click on the **Check
>   Repository** button.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to check all files in a folder to see which files are in need of updating against those that don't need to be?

As @cheran-s wrote, it's possible, but you really don't need it.

Because if during your work in your clean WC somebody commit changes to repo before your attempt

- on commit stage you'll get warning about out-of-sync working copy
- will have "update WC", "merge" and "resolve conflicts"
- only after this workcommit own merged changes